# AsyncPostBackTrigger doesn't find LinkButton

Tags: asp.net, asyncpostbackerror

I have this code in my .aspx file

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>    
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="Placeholder1" EnableViewState="false"></asp:PlaceHolder>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ShowVotePanelBtn" EventName="ShowVoteClick" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And I get this error:
`Could not find an event named 'ShowVoteClick' on associated control 'ShowVotePanelBtn' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'`.

I don't understand this message. The control has the corresponding click event.

Any idea?

Comment: Recreate the event..it might work!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead use:

```
EventName="Click"
```

This will raise your `Click` event of your `LinkButton` control, as defined by its `OnClick` property. In your case, your `ShowVoteClick` event.